# please tell what this php code is doing. (.net reference)

Tags: php, vb.net, arrays

please tell me what is below code doing? is it creating array with two values or its creating to string index which will take value later?

```
 var $requiredValues=Array(
        'MaxResponses',
        'AvailableOnlyIndicator'
    );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$requiredValues=Array(
    'MaxResponses',
    'AvailableOnlyIndicator'
);
```

It is assigning index 0 to value MaxResponses and 1 to value AvailableOnlyIndicator.

So array with two values.

**Note:** var keyword won't work in you are under php 5+.

Comment: Array keyword needs to be lowercased.

Comment: Blanket statements are dangerous. `$var=2;print $Var;`

Answer (score 1):

That code isn't valid php.  This is:

> $requiredValues=Array(
>           'MaxResponses',
>           'AvailableOnlyIndicator'
>    );

That code is creating an array with two elements.

Comment: @Dot Net Developer: The 'var' keyword is no longer valid in PHP5. In PHP5 you have private, public and protected. In PHP4 every property of the class was public.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
<?php array('MaxResponses', 'AvailableOnlyIndicator'); ?>
```

And the array would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MaxResponses
    [1] => AvailableOnlyIndicator
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's creating an array with two values, with an automatic numeric index.  Syntax is slightly off, but it should work.